# Can we disable date, time from hikvision cameras, from curl

Tags: python-3.x, camera, rtsp, hikvision

There are documentation where we can change date and time. Is there any way by which we can disable it. If yes, please let me know.

I have tried the overlay API which is being used, but it takes token id which i feel is not an ideal case.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.